# Marionette - listenTo a custom event triggered from a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using a Event Aggregator(EA) to keep track of all events in my app. But there is one situation I could not make the EA listen to a custom event triggered from a collection. See more details below.

**eMgr** *(Event Manager i.e Event aggregator)*:

```
define(['backbone.wreqr'],function(Wreqr){
    "use strict";
    return new Wreqr.EventAggregator();
})
```

**collection:**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone', 'eMgr', 'models/MainMenu/MM.model.category'], function(_, Backbone, eMgr, m_Category){
  var CategoriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: m_Category,

    initialize: function(options) {
        console.log('CategoriesCollectionView initialized...');
        this.url= 'test1';
        this.fetch().then(function(){
            eMgr.trigger("test1")
        })
    }

  });

  return CategoriesCollection;
});
```

**LayoutView:**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 'eMgr',
            'templates/template.mainmenu', 
            'collections/MainMenu/MM.collection.categories',
            'layouts/MainMenu/collectionview.categories'    ],
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, eMgr, template, c_Categories, cv_Categories) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoryLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

        template: template['categories.layout'],

        regions: {
            categories : '#categories'
        },

        id: 'categories-layout',

        initialize: function(options){
            var r_categories = this.categories;
            this.listenTo(eMgr, "test1", this.test);
            this.categories = new c_Categories(options)
        },

        test: function(){
            console.log("test");
            var categories_layout = new cv_Categories({ collection: this.categories});
            categories_layout.render()
        },

        onRender: function(){
        },

        onShow: function(){

        }
    });

    return CategoryLayoutView;
});
```

As you can see above, what I'm trying to achieve is to render the CollectionView (cv_Categories) once the collection has finished loading all the data.

However it doesn't work unless I listen to the events as follows:

```
eMgr.listenTo(eMgr, "test1", this.test);
```

This will trigger the function , although I'm no longer able to access my LayoutView's methods/variables and so on. So I can't access my collection, and therefore not able to initiate my CollectionView properly.

Now the question is, am I doing anything wrong or does it all work as intended? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `eMgr.on("test1", this.test, this)` to execute `this.test` with `this` as context (note third parameter).This way you keep the access to your view "this" scope and therefore to your view's functions.

If you prefer to use listenTo, then you could do `eMgr.listenTo(eMgr, "test1", this.test.bind(this))`. I find it more redundant and unnecesarily verbose, though.

Comment: One question though, when using `eMgr.on()` does Marionette automatically closes the event once the view is closed or do I have call eMgr.off() manually? ..

Comment: If you want the event to be called only once, then use `eMgr.once()`. Otherwise you'll have to do `eMgr.off().on()` (which is weird, having `once()`).